How can I reduce high CPU usage for auto scroll text
I've created a custom class for macOS that handles horizontal scrolling text.
The scrolling effect works by continuously updating the position of the text using a timer, which calls setNeedsDisplay at very short intervals. However, this approach results in high CPU usage (around 12-14%).
What I've tried:
I considered using CADisplayLink, but it doesn't seem to be available for macOS lower than 14.0
Questions:
How can I optimize this scrolling text implementation to reduce CPU usage?
Is there a better alternative to using a timer for this purpose in macOS?
Would Core Animation be a better approach? If so, how would I implement it?
Code:
import Cocoa

public enum ScrollingDirection {
case leftToRight
case rightToLeft
}

open class ScrollingTextView: NSView {
// MARK: - Open variables
open var attributedText: NSAttributedString?
open var scrollingDirection: ScrollingDirection = .leftToRight
open var isScrollBefore: Bool = false
open var isOut: Bool = false
open var text: NSString?
open var font: NSFont?
open var textColor: NSColor = .headerTextColor {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay(bounds)
    }
}
open var isDelayed: Bool = true
open var spacing: CGFloat = 20
open var length: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        updateTraits()
    }
}

open var backgroundColor: NSColor = .blue
open var delay: TimeInterval = 2 {
    didSet {
        updateTraits()
    }
}
//I use scrollSpeed var for combineText
open var speed: Double = 0.1 {
    didSet {
        updateTraits()
    }
}

open var enableGradient: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        gradientViewLeft?.isHidden = !enableGradient || hideLeftFadeView
        gradientViewRight?.isHidden = !enableGradient || hideRightFadeView
    }
}

open var hideLeftFadeView: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        gradientViewLeft?.isHidden = hideLeftFadeView
    }
}

open var hideRightFadeView: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        gradientViewRight?.isHidden = hideRightFadeView
    }
}

//Enable auto-layout
open override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
    return NSSize(width: stringSize.width + spacing, height: stringSize.height)
}

override open var allowsVibrancy: Bool {
    return false
}

// MARK: - Private variables
private var timer: Timer?
private var point = NSPoint(x: 1000, y: 0)
private var timeInterval: TimeInterval?
private(set) var stringSize = NSSize(width: 0, height: 0) {
    didSet {
        point.x = 0
    }
}
private var timerSpeed: Double? {
    return speed / 130
}
private lazy var textFontAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = {
    return [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font ?? NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]
}()
private var gradientViewLeft: NSView?
private var gradientViewRight: NSView?

// MARK: - Open functions
open func setup(string: String, direction: ScrollingDirection) {
    text = string as NSString
    scrollingDirection = direction
    stringSize = text?.size(withAttributes: textFontAttributes) ?? NSSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    setNeedsDisplay(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
    // updateTraits()
}

open func setupAttributed(attributed: NSAttributedString, direction: ScrollingDirection) {
    attributedText = attributed
    scrollingDirection = direction
    stringSize = attributedText?.size() ?? NSSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    setNeedsDisplay(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
    // updateTraits()
}

open func setTextFontSize(_ fontSize: CGFloat) {
    if let existingFont = textFontAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.font] as? NSFont {
        let newFont = NSFont(name: existingFont.fontName, size: fontSize)
        textFontAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.font] = newFont
        setNeedsDisplay(bounds)
    }
}

public override init(frame: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    setupGradientViews()
}

override open func viewDidUnhide() {
    updateTraits()
}

override open func viewDidHide() {
    clearTimer()
}

required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setupGradientViews()
}

deinit {
    clearTimer()
}

private func setupGradientViews() {
    wantsLayer = false
    layer?.masksToBounds = true
    gradientViewLeft = createGradientView(startColor: notchPanel?.notchView.notchColor ?? .black, endColor: .clear)
    gradientViewRight = createGradientView(startColor: .clear, endColor: notchPanel?.notchView.notchColor ?? .black)
    
    if let gradientViewLeft = gradientViewLeft, let gradientViewRight = gradientViewRight {
        addSubview(gradientViewLeft)
        addSubview(gradientViewRight)
    }
}

private func createGradientView(startColor: NSColor, endColor: NSColor) -> NSView {
    let view = NSView(frame: .zero)
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    view.wantsLayer = false
    view.layer = gradientLayer
    return view
}

override open func layout() {
    super.layout()
    point.y = (frame.height - stringSize.height) / 2.0
    let gradientWidth: CGFloat = 30
    gradientViewLeft?.frame = CGRect(x: -6.0, y: 0, width: gradientWidth, height: bounds.height)
    gradientViewRight?.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.width - gradientWidth, y: 0, width: gradientWidth, height: bounds.height)
}

override open func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    if let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext {
        context.saveGState()
        let clipPath = NSBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        clipPath.addClip()
        
        if point.x + stringSize.width < 0 {
            point.x += stringSize.width + spacing
        }
        
        textFontAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = textColor
        text?.draw(at: point, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
        
        if point.x < 0 {
            var otherPoint = point
            otherPoint.x += stringSize.width + spacing
            text?.draw(at: otherPoint, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
        }
        context.restoreGState()
    }
}

public func stopScrolling() {
    clearTimer()
    point.x = 0
    setNeedsDisplay(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
}
}

    // MARK: - Private extension
    private extension ScrollingTextView {
    func setSpeed(newInterval: TimeInterval) {
    clearTimer()
    timeInterval = newInterval
    
    guard let timeInterval = timeInterval else { return }
    if timer == nil, timeInterval > 0.0, text != nil {
        if #available(OSX 10.12, *) {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: newInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(update(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            
            guard let timer = timer else { return }
            RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    } else {
        clearTimer()
        point.x = 0
    }
}

func updateTraits () {
    clearTimer()
    if stringSize.width >= length {
        guard let speed = timerSpeed else { return }
        if #available(OSX 10.12, *), isDelayed {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: false, block: { [weak self] timer in
                self?.setSpeed(newInterval: speed)
            })
        } else {
            setSpeed(newInterval: speed)
        }
    } else {
        setSpeed(newInterval: 0.0)
    }
}

func clearTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}

@objc
func update(_ sender: Timer) {
    point.x = point.x - 0.5
    setNeedsDisplay(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
 }
}


12-14% is not "high". I worry that you are worrying needlessly. That said, there are lots of horizontal scrolling label implementations out there (hint, this is often called a "marquee" effect); I suggest you do a bit of research.

Hmm thank you in the Xcode it's the energy go to the start of high that's what I mean
